# Comparing Column Values and returning ERROR or OK

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm needing to verify a source system with a destination system and ensure the values are matching between them. The problem is the source system is a total mess and is proving hard to validate.

I've got the following sample data where they should all be OK, but they're showing as ERROR. Does anyone know a way of doing a comparison that would result as an OK for all for the below?

```
CREATE TABLE #testdata (
    ID INT
    ,ValueSource VARCHAR(800)
    ,ValueDestination VARCHAR(800)
    ,Value_Varchar_Check AS (
        CASE 
            WHEN coalesce(ValueSource, '0') = coalesce(ValueDestination, '0')
                THEN 'OK'
            ELSE 'ERROR'
            END
        )
    )

INSERT INTO #testdata (
    ID
    ,ValueSource
    ,ValueDestination
    )
SELECT 1
    ,'hepatitis c,other (specify)' 'hepatitis c, other (specify)'    
UNION ALL    
SELECT 2
    ,'lung problems / asthma,lung problems / asthma'
    ,'lung problems / asthma'    
UNION ALL    
SELECT 3
    ,'lung problems / asthma,diabetes'
    ,'diabetes, lung problems / asthma'    
UNION ALL    
SELECT 4
    ,'seizures/epilepsy,hepatitis c,seizures/epilepsy'
    ,'hepatitis c, seizures/epilepsy'
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma after `'hepatitis c,other (specify)'` ? Also, each value in ValueSource and ValueDestination seems different in the insert data. Example, for ID 1, there is an extra space in ValueDestination. Similarly, for ID 2, ValueSource has repeated values.

Comment: Your computed column references columns that don't actually exist - so that seems a big problem.

Comment: There should be yes, that's the problem with that row, that I'm trying to figure out a way to get them all to match because they do but there slight issues with them relating to spaces, duplicates and wrong order.
Sorry, fixed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can write this as a generated column as it is quite a tricky thing to compute. If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to convert the `ValueSource` and `ValueDestination` values into tables and then sort them alphabetically using a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, TRIM(value) AS value,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TRIM(value)) AS rn
FROM testdata
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ValueSource, ',')
```

For `ValueSource`, this produces:

```
ID  value                   rn
1   hepatitis c             1
1   other (specify)         2
2   lung problems / asthma  1
3   diabetes                1
3   lung problems / asthma  2
4   hepatitis c             1
4   seizures/epilepsy       2
```

You can then `FULL OUTER JOIN` those two tables on `ID`, `value` and `rn`, and detect an error when there are null values from either side (since that implies that the values for a given `ID` and `rn` don't match):

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, TRIM(value) AS value,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TRIM(value)) AS rn
  FROM testdata
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ValueSource, ',')
),
t2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, TRIM(value) AS value,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TRIM(value)) AS rn
  FROM testdata
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ValueDestination, ',')
)
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) AS ID,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.value IS NULL OR t2.value IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Error'
            ELSE 'OK'
       END AS Status
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.rn = t1.rn AND t2.value = t1.value
GROUP BY COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
ID  Status
1   OK
2   OK
3   OK
4   OK
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ded472/20)

You can then use the entire query above as a `CTE` (call it `t3`) to update your original table:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Value_Varchar_Check = t3.Status
FROM testdata t
JOIN t3 ON t.ID = t3.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  ValueSource                                         ValueDestination                    Value_Varchar_Check
1   hepatitis c,other (specify)                         hepatitis c, other (specify)        OK
2   lung problems / asthma,lung problems / asthma       lung problems / asthma              OK
3   lung problems / asthma,diabetes                     diabetes, lung problems / asthma    OK
4   seizures/epilepsy,hepatitis c,seizures/epilepsy     hepatitis c, seizures/epilepsy      OK
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99f38e/1)

Comment: @Philip no worries at all - it was a really interesting problem. I suspect this might not solve 100% of your problems but it should get you close.